# Identify the Listbox Item through specific item

Tags: c#

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            lst.Add(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
        }
        foreach (var item in lst) 
        {
            lst1.Add(item[2].ToString());
        }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        if (lst1.Contains(textBox1.Text))
        {
           // *Need to find that particular item from listbox and clear rest of them*\\
        }
 }
```

my input is

- 1-2-3-4-5
- 6-7-8-9-10
- 1-9-4-2-3
- 7-8-1-4-9

  so when textbox has value 7
  then my listbox must show **6-7-8-9-10** as output and clear rest all items in listbox

Comment: Your question is unclear and your code doesn’t help much either. When you click the button, you check to see if the text in the text box `textBox1` is contained in the `List` `lst1` and if it is then clear the rest of them? You may want to revise you question to make it clear what you are trying to accomplish. From you last comment: _so when textbox has value 7 then my listbox must show 6-7-8-9-10 as output and clear rest all items in listbox_ ???? Your question is unclear. You may want to peruse… [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: my listbox has 4 items if value given in text box is present in any of 2nd character only just show entire value where 2nd character is avaliable in listbox n clear remaining 3

Comment: Could you not simply loop through the `listbox.Items` and remove the rows where the second character does not match the character in the text box?

Comment: can you please show me here...

Comment: Your code above is looping through the `ListBox.Items` and adding its items to the `List` `lst`. Make a similar loop and check the items to match the value in the textbox. There are several ways to accomplish this. Try something and post back if it doesn't work.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i <= lst1.Count-1; i++)
            {
                if (!lst1[i].Contains(textBox1.Text))
                {

                    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                }

            }
just like u mentioned i tried using it... its not wroking out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using what you have posted, I do not understanding what exactly you are trying to achieve. Using the two (2) `List`’s   `lst` and `lst1` looks very odd. Without having more information as to what your ultimate goal is I question why you would do this the way you are.

The code below removes the items in the `ListBox` where the second character does not match the character in the text box. Hope this helps.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (lst1.Contains(textBox1.Text)) {
    int index = lst1.IndexOf(textBox1.Text);
    string temp = listBox1.Items[index].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show("Character: " + textBox1.Text + " Found at index: " + index + " the string is: " + temp);
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    listBox1.Items.Add(temp);
    // *Need to find that particular item from listbox and clear rest of them*\\
  } else {
    MessageBox.Show("Not Found");
  }
}
```